# HapiJS reply being called twice

Tags: unit-testing, hapi.js

I'm getting this error message with the snippet below

```
Unhandled rejection Error: reply interface called twice
```

Note that I'm using `return` for all the reply() interface

```
Locations
    .findOne({
      _id: request.params.id,
      activationCode: payload.activationCode
    }).then((location) => {
      if (!location) {
        return reply(Boom.notFound('Location not found'))
      }
      locationObject = location
      if (payload.password !== payload.confirmPassword) {
        return reply(Boom.badRequest('Password and Confirm Password must match'))
      }
      if (!payload.terms) {
        return reply(Boom.badRequest('Must agree to Terms & Conditions'))
      }
      return newPaymentMethod.save()
    }).then((paymentMethod) => {
        .....
        return user.save() // user is defined at .....
    }).then(() => {
      return reply({ token: helpers.createJwt(userObject) })
    }).catch((err) => {
      return reply(Boom.wrap(err))
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you get caught into this due to the incorrect use of promises. I guess you’re executing your snippet within a route handler where you’ve access to `reply`.

As you’re `return`ing your responses within the promise chain, you both `return` the value to the next `.then` (promise) and also calling the `reply` from the outer scope.

I suggest you use a promise `reject` for errors so that you only need a single `reply(Boom.method())` within the promise’s `.catch()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you chain promises in the end

```
.then(() => {
  return reply({ token: helpers.createJwt(userObject) })
}).catch((err) => {
  return reply(Boom.wrap(err))
})
```

you might call `reply` twice if any of `if` conditions is true.
Easy solution would be to throw error in `if` condition is true - since there is already a `Boom.wrap` in catch block.